# Java Spring - Crud

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, crud

I'm trying to better understand how Spring works. My Java project is split as follows:

-com.exemple.demo

->DemoApplication.java

->UserController.java

-com.exemple.demo.bo

->User.java

-com.exemple.demo.config

->ApplicationConfig.java

-com.exemple.demo.dal

->UserService.java

->UserServiceImpl.java

-com.exemple.demo.dao

->UserDao.java

Problem: I can't access localhost: 8088 / users defined in the controller. I get this error: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for / error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Here are my classes:

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

DemoApplication :

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.dao"})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    
}
```

UserController :

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.bo.User;
import com.example.demo.dal.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "userService")
    UserService userv;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @GetMapping(value="")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Collection<User> getAll(){
        System.out.println("----->getAll");
        logger.debug("Getting all users.");
        return userv.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

User:

```
package com.example.demo.bo;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private String age;
    
    
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    
    public String getNom(){
        return nom;
    }
    
    public String getPrenom(){
        return prenom;
    }
    
    public String getAge(){
        return age;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    
    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }
    
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "User [id=" + id + ", nom=" + nom + ", prenom=" + prenom + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }   

}
```

ApplicationConfig :

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.example.demo.dal.UserService;
import com.example.demo.dal.UserServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.exemple.demo")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean(name = "userService")
    public UserService getTopoService(){
        return new UserServiceImpl();
    }

}
```

UserService :

```
package com.example.demo.dal;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.bo.User;

@Service
public interface UserService {
    
    public void createUser(List<User> user);
    public Collection<User> getAllUsers();
    public Optional<User> findUserById(int id);
    public void deleteUserById (int id);
    public void updateUser (User user);
    public void deleteAllUsers();
    

}
```

UserServiceImpl :

```
package com.example.demo.dal;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demo.bo.User;
import com.example.demo.dao.UserDao;

@Component
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    UserDao dao;

    @Override
    public void createUser(List<User> user) {
        dao.saveAll(user);  
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<User> getAllUsers(){
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findUserById(int id) {
        return dao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUserById(int id) {
        dao.deleteById(id); 
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        dao.save(user); 
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllUsers(){
        dao.deleteAll();
        
    }

}
```

UserDao :

```
package com.example.demo.dao;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.bo.User;

@Repository
public interface UserDao extends MongoRepository<User, Integer> {


}
```

And this is the logs :

```
2021-05-05 10:07:52 - Starting DemoApplication using Java 15.0.1 on LAPTOP-HTN7GNV0 with PID 4076 (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Downloads\demo\demo\target\classes started by Utilisateur in C:\Users\Utilisateur\Downloads\demo\demo)
2021-05-05 10:07:52 - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-05-05 10:07:53 - Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-05-05 10:07:53 - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 133 ms. Found 0 Reactive MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-05-05 10:07:54 - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8088 (http)
2021-05-05 10:07:54 - Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-05-05 10:07:54 - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-05-05 10:07:54 - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-05-05 10:07:54 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1298 ms
2021-05-05 10:07:54 - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-05-05 10:07:54 - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-05-05 10:07:54 - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:7}] to localhost:27017
2021-05-05 10:07:54 - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:8}] to localhost:27017
2021-05-05 10:07:54 - Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=32457200}
2021-05-05 10:07:55 - Tomcat started on port(s): 8088 (http) with context path ''
2021-05-05 10:07:55 - Started DemoApplication in 2.625 seconds (JVM running for 3.011)
2021-05-05 10:08:03 - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-05 10:08:03 - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-05 10:08:03 - Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

The class `DemoApplication` is your starting point. Here you only scan classes in `com.example.demo.dao`. So your ApplicationConfig is not seen and not used. Please try to change it there to `@ComponentScan("com.exemple.demo")`

And then remove the ComponentScan from `ApplicationConfig`. It is not needed.

As a summary i would prefer following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo"})
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
} 

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "userService")
    UserService userv;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Collection<User> getAll(){
        System.out.println("----->getAll");
        logger.debug("Getting all users.");
        return userv.getAllUsers();
    }
}

//No Service Annotation
public interface UserService {
    
    public void createUser(List<User> user);
    public Collection<User> getAllUsers();
    public Optional<User> findUserById(int id);
    public void deleteUserById (int id);
    public void updateUser (User user);
    public void deleteAllUsers();

}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    UserDao dao;

    @Override
    public void createUser(List<User> user) {
        dao.saveAll(user);  
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<User> getAllUsers(){
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findUserById(int id) {
        return dao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUserById(int id) {
        dao.deleteById(id); 
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        dao.save(user); 
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllUsers(){
        dao.deleteAll();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: --> see my answer

Comment: Why do you create a UserService-Bean in your ApplicationConfig? It is created automatically with the Component-Annotation in UserServiceImpl-Class.

Comment: Yes, but when I delete this class, I have this error : Description:

Field userv in com.example.demo.UserController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dal.UserService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dal.UserService' in your configuration.

Comment: You can remove the Qualifier for UserService in UserController

Comment: it doesn't change anything. I have this error now : Field dao in com.example.demo.dal.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.UserDao' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.dao.UserDao' in your configuration.

Comment: Please review your package names and the ComponentScan-Annotation. In your Example the is a typo: "com.exemple.demo" vs "com.example.demo"

Comment: Yes that was that thank you! Now when I go to the address: localhost: 8088 / users I got this error: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed May 05 09:57:12 CEST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Comment: Try to remove the value from GetMapping-Annotation in the Controller. It is not needed here.

Comment: Did the call print the System.out line on console?

Comment: the logs I get are in the last part of my post

Answer (score 0):

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.dao"})
public class DemoApplication {
```

make it

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo"})
public class DemoApplication {
```

Answer (score 0):

When I change it there to @ComponentScan("com.exemple.demo"), I have this error :

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field userv in com.example.demo.UserController required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- userServiceImpl: defined in file [C:\Users\Utilisateur\Downloads\demo\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\dal\UserServiceImpl.class]
- userService: defined by method 'getTopoService' in class path resource [com/example/demo/config/ApplicationConfig.class]

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

Comment: Remove @Service annotation from your UserService interface. You are not injecting interface, but class implementing it.